# Using C# WinForms Designer on Panel instead of Form Again?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, panel

I have the same question, but the answer to use a UserControl will not do.  I also need to create a control container that I can add other controls to at design time so I can add it to yet another container (Splitter Panel) which is not avaialable to me at design time (plugin architecture).   When I make a User Control, it is missing the design time support and all I get are icons when I drop controls onto this surface.

Do I need to add all the design time support myself, or is there something I am missing that has this for me?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use either a Form or UserControl to accomplish any forms design within the designer.

I have often created controls that I need to manipulate en masse. Start with a UserControl, then add a panel that fills the UserControl. This is your base panel that you will fill with all of your controls. I then save as a duplicate control and simply remove the UserControl and leave the panel as the public UI control which is then instanced. If I am making changes, I can go back to the original UserControl, make changes, add code, etc - rinse and repeat.